# SSIS OLE DB Command

Tags: ssis

I have two Sql Server Instances and I want to perform an Update in Server 2 using values from Server 1. Currently I am using OLE DB Command Transformation to update a table in Server 2 but it is extremely slow (takes about 4 hours to update under 100,000 rows). Is there a way to save the records from server 1 in a temp table in server 2 to perform a fast update there. I know this can be done if it was the same servers. Please share some thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Make a permanent table to stage the data. Using a temp table here just seems like extra work.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the answer I provided yesterday?  Did it work for you? Do you need any clarification?

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid the OLE DB Command if at all possible. It executes once for ever record, which explains the long run time you are experiencing. Give this a try:

1. Create a Data Flow Task that loads your required data from Server 1 to a staging table on Server 2. Load only the data you need, i.e. the values you will use in the update and the values you join on.
2. Create an Execute SQL Task that connects to Server 2 and executes your update statement (or stored procedure that contains your update statement).
3. Optionally, you may want another Execute SQL Task that runs before your Data Flow, in which you drop the indexes on your staging table, and then another after the Data Flow that rebuilds your index(es) before your run your update. It may not be worth doing this so be sure to test it both ways and consider how much the data will grow over time.

If you end up using this, let us know in a comment how quickly it ran.